# How to remove mobifoth pop-up from Chromium?

Tags: chromium, malware

I've had this annoying pop-up for the last day on Chromium. It pops up occasionally and seemingly without any pattern. The site is go.mobifoth.co.

I've tried to clean history but it doesn't help. I run Ubuntu 17.04.
How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you installed the "FB Unseen" chrome extension?
It seems from few days age, that it start opening the go.mobifoth tabs.

Ref.
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/6amjo1/malware_warning_if_youve_been_getting_spam_popups/

Comment: Still waiting to see if it works but thanks man.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.